# select row and add/remove Checkmark and add amount swift

Tags: swift, if-statement

I have a table view in a view controller and the result I want to achieve is to add 5 to `var mytotal` for row 1...4 if the row is selected and subtract 5 if the row is deselected.

For the 5th row (the last one) I want to add 10 if the row is selected and subtract 10 if the row is deselected. 
Every time a row is selected a checkmark is added to the right of the cell and when the row is deselected the checkmark is removed.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var mytotal: UILabel!
var total = 0
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var items = ["Inside Cabinets", "Inside Fridge", "Inside Oven", "Interior windows","Laundry wash & dry"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")


}

// number of rows in table
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

    // create the cells
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell")!
    cell.textLabel!.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    var theCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!


    if theCell.accessoryType == .None {
        theCell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        total += 5
    self.mytotal.text = String(total)
    }
    else if theCell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
        theCell.accessoryType = .None

        total -= 5
    self.mytotal.text = String(total)
    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few changes to your code to achieve what you are describing.

First, instead of having simply an array of `String` items, you can create a struct and store your data for each element in there.

```
struct Item {
  var name: String // Name of the row (e.g. "Inside cabinets")
  var isSelected: Bool // Whether or now this item has been selected
  var value: Int // How much you increase your total when selecting this row
}
```

Then in your view controller, you would define your array of `[Item]` as follows:

```
var items = [
    Item(name: "Inside Cabinets", isSelected: false, value: 5),
    Item(name: "Inside Fridge", isSelected: false, value: 5),
    Item(name: "Inside Oven", isSelected: false, value: 5),
    Item(name: "Interior windows", isSelected: false, value: 5),
    Item(name: "Laundry wash & dry", isSelected: false, value: 10)
  ]
```

When dequeuing cells in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, the cells you dequeue are going to be reused if your list of items becomes long enough. Thus, you need to be careful when you check and uncheck cells. As soon as the cell scrolls off the screen, you lose its checked / unchecked status. Moreover, a new dequeued cell might be unexpected selected since the cell is reused.

That is why the `items` array also holds the `isSelected` state. We will use this value to determine, when a cell is dequeued to show on the screen, whether that row had been previously selected or not.

Thus, when we select a row, we will update the data model (`[Item]`) and then tell the tableView to reload the cell at that indexPath. You could also use `tableView.reloadData()`, but it is more costly as it reloads all visible cells.

Reloading the selected/deselected cell calls `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` and refreshes that row within the tableView using the altered data model (`items` array) and the cell will then appear checked or unchecked.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    // Remove the following line. This will create a NEW cell. It is not the same cell that is visible currently on the screen.
    // var theCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    // Toggle the selected state of this cell (e.g. if it was selected, it will be deselected)
    items[indexPath.row].isSelected = !items[indexPath.row].isSelected

    // Update your stored total based on the value of this item
    if items[indexPath.row].isSelected {
      total = total + items[indexPath.row].value
      self.mytotal.text = String(total)
    } else {
      total = total - items[indexPath.row].value
      self.mytotal.text = String(total)
    }

     // Tell the table to reload the cell that has changed
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    tableView.endUpdates()
  }
```

Also note that the +/- 5 and +/- 10 value of each item is also stored within the data model. That way, if you create future items that have a different value, you simply add them to the `items` array and set the item's `value` variable.

One other thing. If you do not want your cells to darken when you select them, you can add the line `cell.selectionStyle = .None` to your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Hope that helps!

**Update 1:**

I fixed `selected` to be `isSelected` in the answer above. Sorry for the typo. Don't forget to include indicating whether a cell has been checked or not in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell")!
    cell.textLabel!.text = self.items[indexPath.row].name // Get name

    // When the the cell scrolls back on screen, you will need to make sure it is checked if this cell was selected before going off the screen,
    // and you need to remove the checkmark on a cell if it is being reused
    if items[indexPath.row].isSelected {
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    } else {
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = .None

    return cell
  }
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues with this code. We cannot create an instance of `Item` with isSelected value because it is not defined in our `struct Item `. If I update the `struct item` with value `isSelected:Bool`, then each item in the `items` array will need to hold `isSelected`. Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/bibscy/fb394bbec379ae3950a2671ed1d9d2e1     . Thanks

Comment: I have now added `var isSelected:Bool` to `struct Item` and also added `isSelected: false` to  `var items`. However, now there are several issues: After I first run the app and click on a row it does not show the checkmark. Afterwards, even if I click a row twice it will keep adding `value` to `total` instead of subtracting and the checkmark does not disappear.  https://gist.github.com/bibscy/059b2037ba81dd95680742a60b991aa2

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on isSelected. The Items struct should only contain "isSelected," not "selected." I accidentally changed the variable name as I was writing my answer. Update your code so the Item struct only has three members (name, isSelected, and value) and ensure you are only updating isSelected in your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath code. This line is likely the culprit: `items[indexPath.row].isSelected = !items[indexPath.row].selected`. Change 'selected' to 'isSelected.' Also, don't forget the code to set your row labels. Check my updated answer.